# magento2 frontend layout extending

Tags: layout, magento2

I want to move search textbox and cart image to left side of top links.
[image]

For this i have created theme **puma** and specified parent as **luma**.
After customer login top links moved to dropdown. Now I want to move search textbox and cart image to left side of top links.

I have identified search textbox is coming from `vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/templates/form.mini.phtml`, and its layout `default.xml` in `vendor/magento/module-search/` and its block name as `topSearch`.

so i have created `Module_Search folder -> layout folder` and **default.xml** file in `app/design/frontend/puma`.

And i wrote `<move element="topSearch" destination="top.links" before="customer"/>` but its not working.

Assume i was perfect till identifying block but i could not identify `destination` value, I have seen `Magento_Theme->page_layout->1column.xml` but could not identify.

Answer (score 6):

I have reviwed your request Please follow below steps.

You need to create ***'Search Module'*** folder under your **puma** theme and copy default.xml into layout

(e.g) puma > Magento_CatalogSearch > layout  > default.xml

To move ***top.search*** you need to write following code in your ***(puma > Magento_CatalogSearch > layout  > default.xml)***

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header.panel" before="header.links"/>
```

To move ***minicart*** you need to write following code in your ***(puma > Magento_Checkout > layout  > default.xml)***

where
***header.panel*** is `<referenceContainer>` of ***header.links*** please review **luma > Magento_Theme > layout > default.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

**or you can also write directly into (puma > Magento_Theme > layout  > default.xml)**

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header.panel" before="header.links"/>
<move element="minicart" destination="header.panel" after="top.search"/>
```

please let me know if it's not working.

Comment: after header links minicart and in last search textbox was placed, but i want textbox before minicart for that i used `<move element="top.search" destination="header.panel" before="-"/>`, but its not working

Answer (score 2):

Extending Satish's answer to address prasad's last comment:

> after header links minicart and in last search textbox was placed, but i want textbox before minicart for that i used , but its not working

Try:

```
move element="minicart" destination="top.links" after="-" />
```

See: [Magento 2: Issue while add custom top links in header](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93157/magento-2-issue-while-add-custom-top-links-in-header)

Answer (score 0):

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link"
                   template="Magento_Customer::account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Need to work on Block folder also 
which is extends from ***\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link implements SortLinkInterface***