# Magento 2: Issue while add custom top links in header

Tags: magento2, toplinks

I am trying to add custom top link via custom module.

File `/app/code/<VendorName>/Inquiry/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

If I used `<referenceBlock name="header.links">` then its working fine.

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="header.links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="inquiry.link" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Inquiry</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">inquiry</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

But, If I used `<referenceBlock name="top.links">` then it is not working.

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="inquiry.link" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Inquiry</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">inquiry</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Can anyone guide me here, what is going wrong with second code? Because in Google search result everywhere peoples has suggested `<referenceBlock name="top.links">` but it is not working in my custom module. As well same code is written in magento 2 core module. I stuck here..

Comment: I think it depend `header.links` but not `top.links`

Comment: @PaW, but in core module magento used `top.links`. file: `\vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\layout\default.xml`

Comment: because it using `<move element="register-link" destination="header.links"/>` in Luma Theme so it move to `header.links`

Comment: Yes, I also got this one. I mentioned it into below answer. Thanks PaW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

I am using luma theme in magento 2. In luma theme new block has been created under `header.panel` container. Luma has Extend the base layout to add a block.

File: `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

while in magento blank theme it has created with the name of `top.links`

File: `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

I got this solution from http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-practice.html